# Add text under and image and then add separate text on the left

Tags: html, css

I have an image that needs a description below (name and title) and then a biography of a couple paragraphs to display wrapped around the image. I tried floating the text to the left and using align="left" in the img tag, but how can I make sure the name and description are fixed below while the paragraph text wraps around the image?  Here is a sample:

```
<div class="info">
    <img src="../img/test.jpg" alt="test pic">
    <br>
    John Doe
    <br>
    President
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam convallis pellentesque orci a pulvinar. Donec rutrum ipsum eget justo venenatis ultricies vel ac mi. Praesent pellentesque libero at porta ultrices. Nullam venenatis velit ut molestie aliquet. Nullam ac justo vestibulum, rhoncus nibh id, tempus ante. Nulla vel enim eu massa congue mattis ut nec erat. In vel rutrum quam, non pellentesque nisi. Vivamus rutrum purus et pellentesque ultricies. Aenean feugiat diam nec lacus placerat, ac elementum nulla iaculis. Nunc accumsan adipiscing arcu sit amet ultrices.</p>           

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam convallis pellentesque orci a pulvinar. Donec rutrum ipsum eget justo venenatis ultricies vel ac mi. Praesent pellentesque libero at porta ultrices. Nullam venenatis velit ut molestie aliquet. Nullam ac justo vestibulum, rhoncus nibh id, tempus ante. Nulla vel enim eu massa congue mattis ut nec erat. In vel rutrum quam, non pellentesque nisi. Vivamus rutrum purus et pellentesque ultricies. Aenean feugiat diam nec lacus placerat, ac elementum nulla iaculis. Nunc accumsan adipiscing arcu sit amet ultrices.</p>
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YR5Ef/ ?

Comment: You actually want to float the div containing the img and the text to the right. Don't worry about the text or positioning the description below the image, those will happen automatically.

Comment: @passerby - that works great, want to post the answer so I can mark it as right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, extending from comment:

Instead of floating the image, you can actually float the whole div:

```css
div.info {
    float:left;
    text-align:center; /* so the text is centered */
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YR5Ef/)